# Walking a folder structure in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I have a requirement to write a Windows application which will walk through a folder structure of a Document Library or OneDrive that it is pointed to and produce an audit of the contents. I'm pretty new to SharePoint development, so I was thinking of using CSOM / CAML to walk through the structure from the root level so as to build output something like this:

Root folder: 10 files, 3 folders
 File 1 ...
 File 2 ...
 File 10...

Folder 1: 0 files, 2 folders
 Folder 1:
 Folder 2:

Folder 2: ...

Folder 3: ...

Etc. But I'm having trouble working out how to enumerate / walk through folder structures... This kind of thing is dead simple on a standard disk, but I'm struggling to get my head around how this works in SharePoint. Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one strategy using REST:

Loop/recurse the folder structure:

```
https://yourDomain/sites/yourSite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Folders
```

then repeat for each child folder:

```
https://yourDomain/sites/yourSite/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/Test Folder')/Folders
```

you can get the files at each path using /Files instead of /Folders.

Here's another approach that starts by returning a list of all folders in a library using a CAML query:

```
/sites/workflowtest/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'FSObjType\' /><Value Type=\'LookUp\'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'}&$select=FileDirRef,fileleafref
```